# Expanding variable with spaces into a curl POST variable

Tags: bash, post, curl, nagios

Some research revealed a few useful stackexchange posts, namely [expanding variable in CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152388/expanding-variable-in-curl), but that given answer doesn't seem to properly handle bash variables that have spaces in them.

I am setting a variable to the output of awk, parsing a string for a substring (actually truncating to 150 characters).  The string I am attempting to POST via curl has spaces in it.

When I use the following curl arguments, the POST variable `Body` is set to the part of the string before the first space.

`curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/GUID/SMS/Messages.xml' -d 'From=DIDfrom' -d 'To=DIDto' -d 'Body="'$smsbody'" -u SECGUID`

`smsbody` is set as:

`smsbody="$(echo $HOSTNAME$ $SERVICEDESC$ in $SERVICESTATE$\: $SERVICEOUTPUT$ | awk '{print substr($0,0,150)}')"`

So the only portion of `smsbody` that is POSTed is `$HOSTNAME$` (which happens to be a string without any space characters).

What is the curl syntax I should use to nest the bash variable properly to expand, but be taken as a single data field?

Seems pretty trivial, but I messed with quotes for a while without luck.  I figure someone with better CLI-fu can handle it in a second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra single quote before *Body*. You also need double quotes or the $smsbody won't be evaluated.

Try this:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/GUID/SMS/Messages.xml' \
    -d 'From=DIDfrom' -d 'To=DIDto' -d "Body=$smsbody" -u SECGUID
```

If the `$`s are still an issue (I don't think spaces are), try this to prepend a `\` to them:

```
smsbody2=`echo $smsbody | sed 's/\\$/\\\\$/g'`
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/GUID/SMS/Messages.xml' \
    -d 'From=DIDfrom' -d 'To=DIDto' -d "Body=$smsbody2" -u SECGUID
```

If I run `nc -l 5000` and change the twilio address to localhost:5000, I see the smsbody variable coming in properly.

```
matt@goliath:~$ nc -l 5000POST / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic U0VDR1VJRDphc2Q=
User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.20
Host: localhost:5000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

From=DIDfrom&To=DIDto&Body=goliath$ $ in $:
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  When I attempted `'Body='$smsbody'`, curl literally sent the string `$smsbody` (literally, not expanding the variable).  I'll try adding the escape character '\' before the space characters using `sed` to the string as you suggest and see if that works!

Comment: I just did an edit, so make sure you are up to date with my answer. Good luck!

Comment: This worked!  Thanks very much!  curl was only able to expand the variable within curl when escaping the space characters. I briefly got stuck trying to pipe twice instead of setting an additional bash variable.  I'll work on this separately.  For now I'll just use the conditional `&&` to (maybe) execute both commands in one line.

Comment: using xargs: `smsbody="$(echo $HOSTNAME$ $SERVICEDESC$ in $SERVICESTATE$\: $SERVICEOUTPUT$ | awk '{print substr($0,0,150)'} | xargs -0 -I {} echo {} | sed 's/\\$/\\\\$/g' )"`  While working this out, I kept missing the double-quotes in the curl POST.  Very important.

Comment: And... the holy grail, all of this in a single line: `echo $(echo $HOSTNAME$ $SERVICEDESC$ in $SERVICESTATE$\: $SERVICEOUTPUT$ | awk '{print substr($0,0,150)'} | xargs -0 -I {} echo {} | sed 's/\\$/\\\\$/g') | xargs -0 -I {} curl -X POST 'localhost:5000' -d 'From=DIDfrom' -d 'To=DIDto' -d "Body={}" -u SECGUID`  Who needs a script!

Comment: oops, looks like there can be problems with the above syntax if $SERVICEOUTPUT$ contains '\', so instead of `echo $(echo` use `echo $(printf "%b"` which will escape all the '\' characters.  Otherwise, another sed parsing will do the trick.

Comment: This will be the last update.  I want to note that I'm having some trouble having the nagios macros expand using the single line two comments above.  Beware.